# How can you speed up the ADC on an ATtiny85?

Tags: arduino-mega, programming, attiny, adc

I'm reading input from a camera and trying to reach a fast frame rate. Problem is my ATtiny85 has a pretty slow conversion time (65 - 260 µs Conversion Time). Is there any way to make this faster? I heard that you can set-up a prescaler for the `analogRead()` method by doing the following:

```
#define FASTADC 1

// defines for setting and clearing register bits
#ifndef cbi
#define cbi(sfr, bit) (_SFR_BYTE(sfr) &= ~_BV(bit))
#endif
#ifndef sbi
#define sbi(sfr, bit) (_SFR_BYTE(sfr) |= _BV(bit))
#endif

void setup() 
{
  #if FASTADC
   // set prescale to 16
   sbi(ADCSRA,ADPS2) ;
   cbi(ADCSRA,ADPS1) ;
   cbi(ADCSRA,ADPS0) ;
  #endif

  /*Rest of the code goes here.*/
}
```

I can't really make sense of the code and I found it on a less then reliable website so I was wondering if any of the gurus on here could let me know if what I'm attempting is possible and if this is the proper way of achieving my goal.

Also, would this also work for the Arduino Mega? I'm currently using it to test and debug my project since the ATtiny84 doesn't have serial output.

Datasheet: http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf

Comment: How many bits of precision do you need? You can speed up the conversion at the cost of loosing precision in the lower bits down to 1us/conversion.

Comment: Can you explain what bits of precision is? This is my first Arduino Project and first time working with a camera so I'm a little confused on the lingo.

Comment: The ATTINY ADC normally gives 10 bits of precision- so you get a value between 0 and 2^10 (1024) and each number is different, so (say) 787 (1100010011) is always bigger than 786 (1100010010) even though 787 and 786 only differ by the lowest bit. You can make the ADC go faster, but the bottom bits start to not matter so you can only care about the topmost bits - so in our case if you only had 9 bits of precision then 786 and 787 would be the same (both would be (110001001x where the x means don't know or care). Make sense?

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. So when you set a prescaler you are reducing the number of bits used we can get the ADC to be faster but we will have less accuracy.

Comment: The prescaler just divides the clock that goes into the ADC. So if you start with a 1MHz clock and a prescaler of `/2`, then the lock that goes into the ADC will be 500Khz. The ADC clock (after the prescaller) needs to be 50-200Khz to get all 10 bits of precision, but you can run it up to 1mhz but more of the bottom bits will start being wrong the faster you go.  How much precision do you need and how fast you do need samples?

Comment: I'd be fine with 4 bits of precision eventually and for me the faster the better. I'm also trying to understand what the code above is doing. Since it's setting a prescaler of 16 does that mean that it's actually making my program slower?

Comment: If you only need 4 bits, then I'd ditch the ADC and just use 2 op amps - or even just a resistor ladder connected to input pins so that you get the voltage window you want. Very very simple (at most 4 resistors) and very fast (as fast as the ATTINY can read the input PINs).

Comment: Sorry again I'm kind of lost with the lingo. What are 2 op amps? And how can I just ditch the ADC if the signal coming in from the clock are in analog?

Comment: What is the camera?

Comment: @bigjosh The TSL1401R-LF linescan module. It reads in a 1 X 128 array of pixels.

Comment: Besides lowering the ADC clock prescaler, you can also do the conversions asynchronously. Arduino's `analogRead` for example, starts a AD conversion, waits till it's finished, and then returns the value. However during this waiting you could be doing something useful. So you could e.g. do something like; start conversion, do some calculations on the previous conversion value, wait till conversion is done, and start all over again.

Answer (score 2):

The ADCs in the ATtiny85 and ATmega2560 (the chip powering the Arduino
Mega 2560) are pretty similar, except for the Mega having more inputs.
In particular, the way you set the clock prescaler is the same, namely
the bits ADPS2:0 in the register ADCSRA. You could use the same code to
set the prescaler on both chips, but you probably don't want to unless
your ATtiny is clocked at 16 MHz, like your Mega. I would normally
just *set* the control register to the value I want, rather than
touching only a few bits, but that is a matter of personal preference.
So, to set the ADC clock of the Mega to 1 MHz, I would

```c++
ADCSRA = _BV(ADEN)    // enable the ADC
       | _BV(ADPS2);  // clock at F_CPU / 16 = 1 MHz
```

The same code would do the same thing on an ATtiny clocked at
16 MHz. If the ATtiny runs at 8 MHz, I would instead

```c++
ADCSRA = _BV(ADEN)    // enable the ADC
       | _BV(ADPS1)   // clock at
       | _BV(ADPS0);  //     F_CPU / 8 = 1 MHz
```

If you want to be generic:

```c++
#if F_CPU >= 12000000
# define ADPS_SETTING _BV(ADPS2)                 // F_CPU / 16
#else
# define ADPS_SETTING (_BV(ADPS1) | _BV(ADPS0))  // F_CPU / 8
#endif

ADCSRA = _BV(ADEN)      // enable the ADC
       | ADPS_SETTING;  // clock somewhere near 1 MHz
```

As bigjosh explained in comments, the prescaler setting is a trade-off
between speed and accuracy. I recommend you read the [article on the
Arduino ADC by Nick Gammon](http://www.gammon.com.au/adc). He did some tests at various speeds
which showed that you can get decent results with clock speeds up to
1 MHz, then it becomes pretty bad at 2 MHz and mostly
useless beyond. You may want to run the same tests with your particular
setup.

Except for the very first conversion, which takes longer, an ADC
conversion takes 13 cycles of the ADC clock. If you run that clock
at 1 MHz, that is 13 µs per reading. If you get the readings
with `analogRead()`, you won't get one reading every 13 µs, because
the CPU needs extra time to execute the code you have between successive
calls of `analogRead()`. You can save time by having the CPU and the ADC
work in parallel, maybe along these lines:

```c++
ADCSRA |= ADSC;     // start the first conversion
for (int i = 0; i < NB_READINGS; i++) {
    loop_until_bit_is_clear(ADCSRA, ADSC);  // wait for the ADC
    uint16_t reading = ADC;     // get the reading
    ADCSRA |= ADSC;             // start the next conversion
    process(reading);           // process the reading we have
}
```

This way you process one reading while the ADC is taking the next one.
Or you can set the ADC to “free running mode” (where it takes one
reading after another without ever stopping) and get the readings in an
interrupt service routine. Whichever method works best depends on your
particular application: the amount of works your CPU has to do while
reading the ADC and whether you can afford to do the whole series of
readings with interrupts disabled.

Comment: If that's how you make the ADC faster then what does the code I posted do?

Comment: It sets the prescaler to 16, just like my first code snippet.

Comment: Okay, then I might be understanding the concept behind a prescaler. I thought prescalers made things slower because they divided the speed at which things happen. Meaning if my ADC is operating at a 1MHz speed and I set a prescaler of 2 then it would run at half the speed.

Comment: @CrystalPritzker: No. The prescaler sits between the CPU clock and the ADC clock. C.f. section 17.5 of the datasheet. If your CPU runs at 16 MHz (which is the case on the Mega), setting the prescaler to 2 would clock your ADC at 8 MHz, way too fast. The Arduino core sets it to 128, which clocks the ADC at 125 kHz, which is fine but too slow for your needs. I suggest you clock your ADC at 1 MHz, which means setting the prescaler to 16 on the Mega (I do not know `F_CPU` on your Tiny).

Comment: I see, but what happens if I just don't set a prescaler? Is their a default speed at which the ADC runs?

Comment: @CrystalPritzker: The hardware defaults to prescaler = 2 (see the datasheet). If you use an Arduino core, it will be set to 128 (c.f. my previous comment).